# How to downgrade arbitrary PDF file to version PDF-1.2?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have some user generated PDF files. Typically the files are be generated with Word, but  they could be just a about any kind of valid PDF file. I'd like convert the file to version PDF-1.2 if they have higher version number. The features available only in higher version (like multimedia) should be removed and the result should be still reasonably reasonable and readable.

How to do this programmatically, without interactive tools such as Adobe Acrobat? Preferably with Java and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)-library, but I would be interested in other solutions also.

One way would be to generate a bunch of images from original PDF and then package them as a PDF-1.2 file, but is the a more elegant way?

Comment: what is the ultimate purpose for this downgrade? Make the PDF more universally readably, like on mobile phones and eBook readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the commandline below. It uses Ghostscript to re-distill the PDF. Use Ghostscript version 8.71 or newer: 9.00. (The wrongly up-voted answer above advicing to *"set PDF version in iText using setPdfVersion()"* will NOT work -- it only re-labels the PDF, which will only be mis-leading...)

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o output-v1.2.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook ^
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.2 ^
    input-v1.6.pdf
```

Comment: The nice thing about features from later versions of PDF is that they're simply ignored by older readers.  That "1.x" at the beginning isn't much more than a suggestion... one the viewer can ignore.  If you drop form fields in your 1.2-marked PDF, I **suspect** Reader will still read/act one the fields and any script they might have.  Oh it might complain about a bad version, but I doubt the fields would break.  iText isn't going to delete all the marked content just because you asked it to set the version to 1.0, nor will it get rid of the color information.  PDF1.0 was gray scale only IIRC.

Comment: I do not advice to use setPdfVersion, I just say you can use that, and I clearly state that downgrading will not work and you will have to strip out objects of higher version manually.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to reprint it through Ghostscript.

Comment: Will that keep the text data as a text, and not generate single large image?

Comment: Most likely not.  If that is a requirement, then you may want to edit your question.

Comment: @Juha Syrjälä: yes, Ghostscript will keep text data as text [though I would not call it "reprint" but "re-distill" it through Ghostscript], provided:  (1) you use the appropriate Ghostscript commmand parameters, and  (2) either the PDF has all used fonts embedded, or  (b) the unembedded fonts used by the PDF are available on all PDF readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the PDF version in iText using [setPdfVersion()](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/interfaces/PdfVersion.html)  however downgrading won't work out of the box I think. You could use PdfCopy and write your pdfs to a new one with the version 1.2 and strip out all none 1.2 objects. Or convert them to version 1.2 objects (which you will have to do yourself I think, not sure however)